How can I deploy smart contracts as container images on a blockchain?
I am trying to build a blockchain that can run complex smart contracts. In order to maintain consistency of environment and avail partial security and isolation, I thought of containers. How can such containers be used in a blockchain to run more complex codes.
Containers that I created are few hundred MBs. It seems impractical to share such large files over a p2p network.

It really depends on how complex your smart contracts will be and what kind of attack surface it creates.
Ethereum has EVM, which is a stack machine with its own instruction set. If smart contracts on your blockchain won't do any complicated operations, you can consider implementing something similar. Also, since it's open-sourced, you can consider using EVM directly in your blockchain.
Alternatively, WASM is potentially a good choice. A WASM file is literally an executable file, so it shouldn't be too large. There are also WASM runtimes that are fast, secure, and provide good isolation.
You can also consider microVMs if you want to make something crazy. It's essentially a VM that has fast startup time and low memory overhead at the expense of some functionalities, so you can run pretty much anything in it. Most microVMs I've seen are for running serverless functions in data centers.
Hope it helps.

Hi @PSave. Please consider upvoting or marking this answer as the approved answer if you think it solves your problem. Or continue the discussion in the comment section if you have further questions.
